Emails and Phone Numbers not added to Database when creating a new Contact
I am working on a Phonebook web app using ASP.NET Core with EF Core for backend.
I have 3 model classes: Contact, Email and Phone with one-to-many relations.
Each contact can have multiple emails and phone numbers.
When I tried to add a new contact through Swagger UI, I've noticed it didn't save emails and phone numbers but only the contact details. I have also tried to manually add email and phone number and after trying it in Swagger UI, I received contact details but with empty arrays of emails and phone numbers again...
I will post my code here and hopefully someone can see where I've messed up.
Thanks in advance everyone.
ContactController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using incubis_assignment.Data;
using incubis_assignment.Models;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

namespace incubis_assignment.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ContactController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public ContactController(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Contact>>> GetContacts()
        {
            return await _context.Contacts.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> GetOneContact(int id)
        {
            var contact = await _context.Contacts.FindAsync(id);

            if (contact == null) 
                return NotFound();

            return contact;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> PostContact(Contact contact)
        {
            contact.Id = 0;
            _context.Contacts.Add(contact);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var resourceUrl = Url.Action(nameof(GetContacts), new { id = contact.Id });
            return Created(resourceUrl, contact);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutContact(int id, [FromBody] Contact contact)
        {
            if (id != contact.Id) 
                return BadRequest();

            _context.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ContactExists(id)) 
                    return NotFound();
                else 
                    throw;
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteContact(int id)
        {
            var contact = await _context.Contacts.FindAsync(id);

            if (contact == null) 
                return NotFound();

            _context.Contacts.Remove(contact);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool ContactExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Contacts.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}

AppDbContext:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using incubis_assignment.Models;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;

namespace incubis_assignment.Data;

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Emails)
            .WithOne(e => e.Contact)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ContactId)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Phones)
            .WithOne(p => p.Contact)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ContactId)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

Contact model class:
namespace incubis_assignment.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; } = new List<Email>();
        public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; } = new List<Phone>();
    }
}

Email model class:
namespace incubis_assignment.Models
{
    public class Email
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Category {  get; set; }

        public Contact Contact { get; set; } // Navigacijsko svojstvo, nema potrebe za null!
    }
}

Phone model class:
namespace incubis_assignment.Models
{
    public class Phone
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ContactId { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public Contact Contact { get; set; } // Navigacijsko svojstvo, nema potrebe za null!
    }
}

I followed the docs but they didn't help much nor did the ChatGPT - it only made it worse...
I don't know if it's because phone and email entries are only ones with JSON input:


When adding contact, you are populating only Contact entity? Are there any related email/phone number to be saved?

@MichałTurczyn yes, there should be saved email and phone number related to the person I'm adding to the database, but only person's name and surname get saved.

@Fildor I agree, but for someone who is still going to faculty and is a beginner in a new language chatgpt is the first thing you can think of for some help...

@Fildor I didn’t ask for upbringing here if you want to have a rant go have it somewehre else, thanks.

To answer my own question:
In Program.cs file I've added:
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReferenceHandler.Preserve
});

Also, I've included Emails and Phones Attributes in the Controller:
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> GetOneContact(int id)
{
    var contact = await _context.Contacts.Include(c => c.Emails).Include(c => c.Phones).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id);
    if (contact == null) return NotFound();
    return contact;
}

In the end, I've added [JsonIgnore] annotation to my Contact attribute in both Phone and Email models.

You could also try this below POST method in controller:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Contact>> PostContact(Contact contact)
{
    // Ensure emails have the correct Contact reference
    if (contact.Emails != null && contact.Emails.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var email in contact.Emails)
        {
            email.Contact = contact; // Setting the contact reference manually
            _context.Entry(email).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }

    // Ensure phones have the correct Contact reference
    if (contact.Phones != null && contact.Phones.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var phone in contact.Phones)
        {
            phone.Contact = contact; // Setting the contact reference manually
            _context.Entry(phone).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
    }

    contact.Id = 0;  // To ensure the new contact gets added with a new ID
    _context.Contacts.Add(contact);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  // Save changes to the database

    var resourceUrl = Url.Action(nameof(GetOneContact), new { id = contact.Id });
    return Created(resourceUrl, contact);  // Return a successful response with the new contact
}

Email.cs:
public class Email
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ContactId { get; set; }
     public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
     public string Category { get; set; }
     public Contact? Contact { get; set; }
 }

Phone.cs:
public class Phone
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ContactId { get; set; }
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public string Category { get; set; }
     public Contact? Contact { get; set; }
 }

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(x =>
        x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve); // This avoids the circular reference issue

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Add DbContext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Result:




Thank you for help! I will for sure try this method as well and leave feedback if it worked for me.

@FraneKrapić  let me know if you face any issue
